# Python Tkinter Text Search for Specific Number Occurences

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way I can search a specific `range` in a `Tkinter` `Text` widget? I don't want to search all the `occurrences` but only a certain number of the `occurrences` (like 5).

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I'm trying to use the search function but it returns all of the occurences.

Comment: Can you show small code of what currently you are using? What it is returning for what input and what you want it to return instead?

Comment: I want to cut my hand.
but without blood flow.
(use of carbon dioxide)

Comment: You say you just one a certain number of occurrences, but based on what you want these occurrences? Do you want to highlight them? What do you want to do? I will down vote this question because IMO it's not clear what you want to do, and you make us only lose time. Please, add more details, possible attempts, and explain better, and I'll remove my down vote.

Comment: Sidenote: Using \` to emphasize words looks odd, especially as this usually means source code snippets, function or variable names, types, … here.  Better use \_ for _simply emphasized words_ or \*\* for **strong emphasized words**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to search for only *N* occurrences. The search command returns a single match. You can search five times, each time starting after the previous match.